# Import facebook contacts into my app

Tags: android, facebook

Is there any way to import the contacts from the facebook into the Android application developed.

I have a basic user login page in which user will provide email & password for logging in . Using the credentials from my application I want to import the contacts from the facebook.

Comment: Hello, this link could help you : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a request from your app. It will return the list of friends. This is the url for getting friend list (`id` is your Facebook id): `https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"?fields=friends&access_token="+access_token`